# CSS :hover-function is working for one class but not for a second

Tags: html, css, hover

Hey I started to learn Html.
But I have a problem with the :hover-function.
I created buttons and when i go with the mouse over them the text gets underlined so you see which button you are on. But i wanted also that a Dropdownmenu appears. And thats the Problem my second class that is connected with a :hover function doesn't appear.

Here the snippet for the blue bar(working)

```html
/*Übergruppe*/
.button{   
    height: 73px;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-color: transparent;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    /*Font*/
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    /*cursor*/
}

.balken{
    opacity: 1; 
}

.button:hover + .balken{
    background-color:  rgba(108, 155, 243, 0.945);
    height: 4px;
    /*Position*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
}


/*CSS-Klassen*/
.UeberCFG{   
    left: 470px;
    border-right-width: 17px;
}
.balkenUeberCFG{
    width: 80px;
    /**/
    left: 475px;
```

And here in another CSS-file the text for the dropdownmenu. I imported the needed CSSfile. I once also tried to put all into one CSS file but this showed also no succes and yes it is linked to the HTML-file.

```html
@import url(../CSS-Data/Buttons.css);
@import url(../CSS-Data/Header.css);

/*Übergruppen*/
.Dconfig{
    opacity: 1;
}
.button:hover + .Dconfig{
    background-color: rgb(223, 217, 217);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /*Position*/
    position: absolute;
    top:70px;
}

/*Untergruppen*/

.DUeberCFG{
left: 470px;

}
```

Here how it looks like(I miss a light-grey box below the blue bar)
[image: Balken]

### Snippet

```css
header {    
    background-color: black;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;  
}   

/*ButtonsCSS*/

.button{   
    height: 73px;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-color: transparent;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
   
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.balken{
    opacity: 1; 
}

.button:hover + .balken{
    background-color:  rgba(108, 155, 243, 0.945);
    height: 4px;
 
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
}


.UeberCFG{   
    left: 470px;
    border-right-width: 17px;
}
.balkenUeberCFG{
    width: 80px;
    /**/
    left: 475px;
}

/*DropdownCSS*/


.Dconfig{
    opacity: 1;
}
.button:hover + .Dconfig{
    background-color: rgb(223, 217, 217);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
   
    position: absolute;
    top:70px;
}

.DUeberCFG{
left: 470px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">


<body>
  <header>      

    <div class="Buttons">          
      <button class="button UeberCFG">Über CFG</button>
      <div class="balken balkenUeberCFG"></div>
    </div>    

    <div class="Dropdownmenue">
        <div class="Dconfig DUeberCFG"></div>  
        <div class="Suchleiste"></div>         
    </div>

      </header> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show us your markup, too. The code snippets are not very helpful without that. See [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hold on, has your dropdown menu got _no content_? Not text, nothing? Because a 0x0 element will be hard to see. Also, the `:hover + .Dconfig ` won't actually do anything, as there's no class `Dconfig` in your HTML, let alone one _directly after a button_, so that one doesn't apply at the moment. And that's all the `:hover` we can look at here...

Comment: Well I did exact the same with .balken and it worked.
And i have Dconfig with DUeberCFG so its in the HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only work with .class + .class if the second is direct next after the first closing.

Look here: [W3CSchools]
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Another example is, to work in one container, so you dont need to use the element selector + from css2. The better way for trainees is to work with a framework like bootstrap. There you got everything you need.

But here is an example about what i mean, to work in the same container.
Its just a example, not a more recommendable codesnippet. More like a mess ;)

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
<div class="button">Ich bin ein Button
<div class="dropdown">
<ul>
<li>Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
<li>Menu 5</li>
<li>Menu 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
#mainwrapper {
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.button, .dropdown {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #181818;
  font-family: arial;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  }

li:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button:hover .dropdown {display:block;height: 410px;}
```

[An here is the Fiddle:]
[2]: https://jsfiddle.net/ew7cu3oj/3/

Comment: but now it only showes the dropdown box ^^
Is it possible to have two boxes at the exact same spot and you can hover them both?

Comment: im not sure to understand you right. how/why would you have two boxed hiding by itself? That makes no sense for me. When you overlay items in html the one with lower z-index is not reachable. When you gave the upper one ```pointer-events: none``` you can click through it but never both if overlaying. Or do you want to create a horizontal navigation?

Comment: well i want two events thats the problem i have :D